# How to update json property of TimeStamp in oracle

Tags: json, oracle, sql-update

I have one of the column `audit_info` with JSON data in the table:

```json
{
  "AddInfo":{
    "UPN":"abc@abc.com",
    "UserName":"abc@abc.com",
    "TimeStamp":"2021-10-11T15:54:34:4805634Z",
    "Source":"xyz"
  },
  "ChangeInfo":{
    "UPN":"abc@abc.com",
    "UserName":"abc@abc.com",
    "TimeStamp":"2021-10-11T15:54:34:4832421Z",
    "Source":"xyz"
  }
}
```

I need to update TimeStamp of seconds decimal point from `:4832421Z` to `.4832421Z`

Can anyone please help me?

```
update the_table
  set audit_info=??
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Original Question:

If you do not have `{:}` anywhere else then you can use replace:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET audit_info = REPLACE(audit_info, '{:}', '{.}');
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1DLmvKS_)

#### Updated Question:

On later Oracle versions, if you want to update the last `:` to `.` in the paths `$.AddInfo.TimeStamp` and `$.ChangeInfo.TimeStamp` then you can use use `JSON_TABLE` to extract the timestamps and then simple string functions to extract the components before and after the last `:` and then use `JSON_MERGEPATCH` to update the specific paths:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT t.ROWID AS rid,
         JSON_OBJECT(
           KEY 'AddInfo' VALUE JSON_OBJECT(
             KEY 'TimeStamp'
             VALUE SUBSTR(addinfo_ts, 1, INSTR(addinfo_ts, ':', -1) - 1)
                   || '.' || SUBSTR(addinfo_ts, INSTR(addinfo_ts, ':', -1) + 1)
           ),
           KEY 'ChangeInfo' VALUE JSON_OBJECT(
             KEY 'TimeStamp'
             VALUE SUBSTR(changeinfo_ts, 1, INSTR(changeinfo_ts, ':', -1) - 1)
                   || '.' || SUBSTR(changeinfo_ts, INSTR(changeinfo_ts, ':', -1) + 1)
           )
         ) AS patch
  FROM   table_name t
         CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
           t.audit_info,
           '$'
           COLUMNS
             addinfo_ts   VARCHAR2(30) PATH '$.AddInfo.TimeStamp',
             changeinfo_ts VARCHAR2(30) PATH '$.ChangeInfo.TimeStamp'
          ) j
) src
ON (src.rid = dst.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET audit_info = JSON_MERGEPATCH(audit_info, src.patch);
```

Then, for the sample data, after the `MERGE` the table contains:

| AUDIT_INFO |
| --- |
| {"AddInfo":{"UPN":"abc@abc.com","UserName":"abc@abc.com","TimeStamp":"2021-10-11T15:54:34.4805634Z","Source":"xyz"},"ChangeInfo":{"UPN":"abc@abc.com","UserName":"abc@abc.com","TimeStamp":"2021-10-11T15:54:34.4832421Z","Source":"xyz"}} |

---

If you do not want to worry about specific paths then you can use a regular expression to match the timestamp:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET audit_info = REGEXP_REPLACE(
                   audit_info,
                   '("TimeStamp"\s*:\s*"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}):(\d+Z")',
                   '\1.\2'
                 );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/U8xLYaU8)

Comment: Thanks @MT0  for reply .. i updated my query can u look into it

Comment: having performance problem @MT0, its taking more time

Comment: having lacks of records

Answer (score 0):

Try replace. This replace the json field an text and then you convert it again an json. It should be something like this:

```sql
update [name_of_the_table]
set audit_info = replace(audit_info::TEXT, ':', '.')::jsonb
where
....
```

Comment: Thank for reply @dany.. but i want to update in particular position (mile seconds).

Comment: Then it's simple:

update table_name
set audit_info = replace(audit_info::text, ':4832421Z', '.4832421Z')::jsonb
where .....

Comment: need dynamic update @dany